Post logout URI does not match with registered callback URI
I am trying to integrate SSO using wso2 identity server 5.11 in my Dot Net Core web application. I have made required configurations and successfully done with the login part however while logging out I am getting the error as "Post logout URI does not match with registered callback URI." I have double check all URLs and made changes in identity server as well but unable to achieve logout. Here is my startup.cs class
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.CallbackPath = "/home/index";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.MetadataAddress = _configuration["Idp:Address"] + _configuration["Idp:MetadataAddress"];
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.ClientId = _configuration["Idp:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = _configuration["Idp:ClientSecret"];
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("address");
    options.Scope.Add("phone");
    options.BackchannelHttpHandler = _handler;

});

This is my action in contoller
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5001/home/index" }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

Still getting this error.

This is the configuration in identity server


What is the callback url that you have configured ?

In current WSO2 IS implementation (including 5.11.0), the post logout uri is validated against the callback uri that you have configured [1] and therefore, if your call back uri and post logout uri does not match, it will result in an error as mentioned above.
This concern is currently tracked with the git issue [2].
[1] - https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/5c3c468b6158dc4e4e82fdfe783be0d86d4cd556/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oidc.session/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oidc/session/servlet/OIDCLogoutServlet.java#L378-L382
[2] - https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/6397
